# Обработка платежей Tinkoff

Tags: javascript, python, платежи

В общем скоро собираюсь сделать проект с использование Тинькофф Кассы для оплаты заказов.

```
import hashlib
import requests

params = {
    "TerminalKey": "TerminalKey",
    "Amount": 19200,
    "OrderId": "21095",
    "Description": "Подарочная карта на 1000 рублей"
}

# params = {
#   "TerminalKey": "TerminalKey",
#   "OrderId": 21090,
# }

password = "password"

token_gen = []

for key, value in params.items():
    if key not in ("Receipt", "DATA", "Token"):
        token_gen.append({key: value})

token_gen.append({"Password": password})


token_gen = sorted(token_gen, key=lambda x: list(x.keys())[0])
token_gen = "".join(str(list(item.values())[0]) for item in token_gen)

sha256 = hashlib.sha256()
sha256.update(token_gen.encode('utf-8'))
token = sha256.hexdigest()

params["Token"] = token

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
}

init_url = 'https://securepay.tinkoff.ru/v2/Init'
chech_order_url = 'https://securepay.tinkoff.ru/v2/CheckOrder'

response = requests.post(init_url, headers=headers, json=params)
print(response.json())
```

Ничего особо просто формирование платежа. В данном случае `init_url` - это запрос для инициализации платежа, а `chech_order_url` для проверки статуса. После создания платежа возвращается ссылка такого вида
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переходишь, оплачиваешь и попадаешь на страницу своего сайта. Все в общем легко и понятно, но хочу узнать как мне отслеживать оплачивание каждого счета, т.е. я хочу чтобы как-то после оплаты мне приходили данные и я формировал уже заказ. В документации ничего вроде как не нашел, но вот она [тык](https://www.tinkoff.ru/kassa/dev/payments/#tag/Scenarii-oplaty-po-karte/Pravila-raboty). Сайт буду писать на `React` + `Django DRF`, если это имеет значение.